# Checkbox array for days of the week

Tags: checkboxes

I'm attempting to create something within my template using global values and checkboxes. What I need this to do is "if it's one of the days of the week marked as open, as selected by a checkbox, and the time is between X and Y, then display that we are open, otherwise, say we are closed".

I have Monday through Sunday listed as checkboxes, and their values are set with Monday as 1, Tuesday as 2, etc, and I'm trying to compare it to 'now'|date('N'), which lists the day of the week as a number.

```
{% for dayOfWeek in theCenter.openWeekDay %}

    {% if 'now'|date('N') == dayOfWeek and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') > theCenter.openTime|date('Hi') and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') < theCenter.closeTime|date('Hi') %}
        <h3>We are OPEN</h3>
    {% else %}
        <h3>We are CLOSED</h3>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I've selected Tuesday through Sunday as open by selecting their checkboxes in the globals form. The code above returns 5 'We are Closed' and 1 'We are Open' results. I just need it to check if today is one of the open days, and if it's between open and closing time, and display one result.

I've tried this:

```
{% if 'now'|date('N') in dayOfWeek and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') > theCenter.openTime|date('Hi') and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') < theCenter.closeTime|date('Hi') %}
```

but it returns 6 'We are Closed'. I've been trying to figure this out for several hours, but the documentation doesn't seem to be made for what I want to do, and I'm probably looking in the wrong place.

Any suggestions on how I could get this to work?

**EDIT**

Here's the entire script:

```
{% if 'now'|date('z', 'America/Denver') > theCenter.startWinterSeason|date('z') or 'now'|date('z', 'America/Denver') < theCenter.endWinterSeason|date('z') %}
    {% for dayOfWeek in theCenter.openDaysWinter %}
        {% if dayOfWeek.selected and 'now'|date('N') == dayOfWeek and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') > theCenter.openTimeWinter|date('Hi') and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') < theCenter.closeTimeWinter|date('Hi') %}
            <h3>The center is OPEN</h3>
        {% else %}
            <h3>The center is CLOSED</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="infoPane">
        <p><i class="uk-icon-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;{{ theCenter.hoursTitleWinter }}</p>
        <p>Tuesday &mdash; Saturday<br>{{ theCenter.openTimeWinter|date('g:i A') }} to {{ theCenter.closeTimeWinter|date('g:i A') }}</p>
        <p class="uk-text-small">{{ theCenter.timeNotes|raw }}</p>
    </div>

{% elseif 'now'|date('z', 'America/Denver') > theCenter.startSummerSeason|date('z') and 'now'|date('z', 'America/Denver') < theCenter.endSummerSeason|date('z') %}
    {% for dayOfWeek in theCenter.openDaysSummer %}
        {% if dayOfWeek.selected and 'now'|date('N') == dayOfWeek and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') > theCenter.openTimeSummer|date('Hi') and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') < theCenter.closeTimeSummer|date('Hi') %}
            <h3>The center is OPEN</h3>
        {% else %}
            <h3>The center is CLOSED</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="infoPane">
        <p><i class="uk-icon-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;{{ theCenter.hoursTitleSummer }}</p>
        <p>Tuesday &mdash; Saturday<br>{{ theCenter.openTimeSummer|date('g:i A') }} to {{ theCenter.closeTimeSummer|date('g:i A') }}</p>
        <p class="uk-text-small">{{ theCenter.timeNotes|raw }}</p>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <h3>EPIC FAIL</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Which outputs this:

[image: Output]

I need it to only show the center is closed once.

Comment: I just setup a test case using virtually identical code and it worked as expected for me.  Is your Craft install set to `America/Denver` under Settings->General?  Also, have you seen https://github.com/pixelandtonic/StoreHours?

Comment: I'll test out Store Hours and see if that works. Is there more documentation available on it?

Also, the timezone is indeed, set to Denver.

Comment: I'm looking at this, and I realise that the reason it's spitting out "We are Closed" so many times is because it's stuck a loop. The hours are simple enough that we just want the hours listed on the site as "The center is open. Hours: Tuesday-Sunday, 9:00 AM to 4:30 PM" -- we don't want to list the hours out for each day of the week individually.

Comment: Hey @BradBell -- thanks for the Store Hours suggestion, but it's not giving me the level of control that I would need. I'll need to stick with this one for now.

Comment: I'm not following... the hours aren't being output at all, it's just looping on the days.  Is your `openTime` and `closeTime` date/time fields set to just display the times?

Comment: The hours are output farther on. I didn't include that part of the script for brevity sake, as this is what I was having issues with. :)

Comment: @BradBell - Added the full script on the original post.

Comment: Regardless, I was able to get it to work with your original code.  So I'd probably focus on that.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood.  If it's closed you only want it to show once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
{% set closed = true %}

{% for dayOfWeek in theCenter.openWeekDay %}

    {% if 'now'|date('N') == dayOfWeek and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') > theCenter.openTime|date('Hi') and 'now'|date('Hi', 'America/Denver') < theCenter.closeTime|date('Hi') %}
        {% set closed = false %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% if closed %}
    <h3>The center is CLOSED</h3>
{% else %}
    <h3>The center is OPEN</h3>
{% endif %}
```